# What permission's are needed to access the Google Email Settings API?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-email-settings-api

There doesn't seem to be a clear documentation for what permissions are actually required for this API, or an obvious way to allow it in the domain dashboard.

I have a script that works when a "Super Administrator" uses it - but not when a "Administrator" tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Email Settings API can only be used by user with full administrative rights over the domain, i.e. super administrators.